# Best technique to style badge

Tags: html, css

How you would style counter badge for example facebook notification? the value is not necessary one digit. It can be one or two. Also in my attempt I don't see how I can center the value.

```css
#counter {
  display: block;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  padding: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 12px;
  left: 0;
  top: 10px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<span id="counter">12</span>
```

Try to change the value to 1 digit, it doesn't look center again. It's slightly off.

Comment: add `line-height` to bring it to the center

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
#counter {
  display: block;
  padding: 2px 4px;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 12px;
  left: 0;
  top: 10px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  line-height:18px;
}
```

```html
<span id="counter">111</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#counter {
  display: block;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  padding: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 12px;
  left: 0;
  top: 10px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  line-height:18px;
}
```

```html
<span id="counter">1</span>
```